# Find $dy/dx$ when $y=2$ given $\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}=k \left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)^2$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

$$\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}=k \left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)^2$$
If $dy/dx=1$ when x=0 and y=1 , what is the value of $dy/dx$ when $y=2$?

Would you need to find the value of k? If yes, how would you find this value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we let $u(x)=y'(x)$, then the equation for $u$ is:
$$u'(x)=ku^2(x)$$
$$\frac{1}{u^2(x)}u'(x)=k$$
$$-\frac{1}{u(x)}=kx+c$$
And after redefining the constant we get that
$$u(x)=\frac{1}{c-kx}$$
So we have that:
$$y'(x)=\frac{1}{c-kx}$$
$$y(x)=-\frac{1}{k}\log(c-kx)+d$$
From $y(0)=1$ we have that
$$1=-\frac{1}{k}\log(c)+d$$
And from $y'(0)=1$ we have that
$$1=\frac{1}{c}$$
So $c=1$ and $d=1$. Now let's set $y=2$
$$2=-\frac{1}{k}\log(1-kx)+1$$
$$-k=\log(1-kx)$$
$$1-kx=e^{-k}$$
So $y'(x)$ when $y=2$:
$$y'(x)=\frac{1}{e^{-k}}$$
$$y'(x)=e^k$$

Comment: how would you find the value of k?

Comment: @Moon We have that $y'(0)=1$ and $y'(1)=1$?

Comment: I understand the first one but the second one is confusing

Comment: @Moon But what do you mean by "If $dy/dx=1$ at $(0,1)$"? Does it mean that $dy/dx=1$ at $x=0$ and at $x=1$, or when $x=0$, $y=1$?

Comment: It means the second one. x=0 and y=1

Comment: @Moon I think we can't get rid of $k$.

Answer (score 1):

Set $u=e^{-ky}$ then $u''=(-ky''+k^2y'^2)u=0$ and thus $u=ax+b$, $y=-\frac1k\ln(ax+b)$.

---

Or another shortcut, as $y$ is assumed to not be constant, change the independent parameter to $y$, set $y'=u(y)$, then $y''=u'(y)y'=u'u$ and the ODE reduces to

> $u'=ku$ with $u(1)=1$ and looking for $u(2)$.

This be answered without ever computing the function $y(x)$.